# Не понимаю как парсить таблицы с сайта. BeautifulSoup не полностью парсится сайт

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть сайт *(https://loliland.net/team)*, с которого мне нужно парсить таблицы с никами и должностями. Когда я пытаюсь получить div из body, то получаю

```
<div id="app">
</div>
```

(сам код выглядит примерно так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import requests

url = 'https://loliland.net/team/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
t1 = soup.find('body')
t2 = t1.find('div')

print(t2.prettify())
```

)

хотя судя по элементам там есть ещё куча вложенных div со своими классами, как мне их запарсить?

Comment: пробуйте через селенимум

Answer (score 0):

requests получает голый html, а сайт динамический. То есть информация на нем автоматически появляется после загрузки страницы. А requests не может исполнить js, по этому в ответе и нет нужной инфы. Попробуй селениум